# Syncing citation keys changes in both bib and tex files

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, jabref

I have a tex file citing some references from a bib file. I want to reformat (i.e. regenerate) all the citation keys in the bib file using JabRef and automatically propagate the changes to the tex file. Does someone know a way of automatically keeping both files synchronized?

Comment: Welcome! You question isn't very clear. Citation keys are plain text - you can't format them. If you mean that you want to change them, how would the system know which key to substitute for which? The key **is** the way the system recognises which `.bib` entry you mean to cite. If you change the key, there is nothing for it to recognise. That said, if you use Biblatex, you can put the old key into the `ids` field and then the entry will still be found, even though the `.tex` file only uses the old key. This is what I do when I want to change a citation key. That way, existing files still work.

Comment: The other thing you could do is write something like a `sed` script and apply it to the two files. Then they'd be in sync because you'd make the same changes in both. But you'd need to make sure to avoid spurious matches. Possibly `gawk` might do it a bit more safely, if there's a risk of matches on other lines. Whether JabRef would like your doing this I know not, but they are all just text files, after all, so you can use the standard text processing tools on them.

Comment: With JabRef, one can press Ctrl+G to generate BibTeX keys following a [pattern](http://help.jabref.org/en/BibtexKeyPatterns). When doing that in JabRef, only the `bib` file changes, but not the `tex` files referencing the `bib` file. I think, this is a feature wish for JabRef. You could bring up that in the [forum](http://discourse.jabref.org/) or just go ahead an implement it directly in [JabRef's source](https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I updated the question. I think now it is a bit more clear. I want to do exactly what @koppor said. I will take a look into JabRef's code to see what I can do.

Answer (score 1):

This simple project solved the key and cite renaming problem:

https://github.com/dmpalyvos/bibtex-rename

It's a simple code, you must

1. Clone the bibtex-rename with `git clone https://github.com/dmpalyvos/bibtex-rename`
2. Rename the bibkey of your file `sample.bib`, and save as `sample_new.bib`.
3. Install the bibtex parser: `pip install bibtexparser`.
4. Execute `python transform.py --tex main.tex --oldbib sample.bib --newbib sample_new.bib --out out.tex`.

Check and ensure that the itens are in the same order,and if you are citing the BibTeX item with `\cite{bibkey}`.